How to Implement Limited Contact Picker in iOS 18 with CNContactPickerViewController?
I am currently using CNContactPickerViewController in my Swift app to allow users to select contacts. With the introduction of the new iOS 18 feature for Limited Contact Access, I want to modify my implementation so that only the contacts selected by the user in the Limited Contact Access permission screen are displayed.
Is there a way to show only the limited contacts in the CNContactPickerViewController once the user grants permission for Limited Contact Access in iOS 18? If so, what adjustments do I need to make in the Swift code to support this?
Here’s the current Swift code I’m using for the contact picker:
@IBAction func addContactBtnEvent(_ sender: Any) {
        PermissionsService.shared.requestContactsAccess { [weak self] isGranded in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if isGranded {
                    if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
                        if CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) == .limited {
                            // Fetch limited access contacts
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
                        self?.presentContactPickerViewController()
                    }
                } else {
                    self?.showContactSettingsAlert()
                }
            }
        }
    }

func requestContactsAccess(completion: @escaping (_ granted: Bool) -> Void) {
        let contactStore = CNContactStore()
        let authorizationStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts)
        switch authorizationStatus {
        case .authorized:
            completion(true)
        case .denied, .restricted:
            completion(false)
        case .limited:
            completion(true)
        case .notDetermined:
            contactStore.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { granted, error in
                if granted {
                    completion(true)
                } else {
                    completion(false)
                }
            }
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }

func presentContactPickerViewController() {
        let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contactPicker.delegate = self
        contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "%K.@count > 0", CNContactPhoneNumbersKey)
        self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


I think the two concepts are independent. Limited contact access is used to control which contacts your app can access without further user action. It is an alternative to allowing apps to simply access all of the users contacts whenever they like. The contact picker allows the user to provide a specific contact to the app and would typically be used for scenarios such as addressing an outgoing communication. Showing the full set of contacts rather than limited contacts in this case is fine because the user still has control over what is shared with the app

If you do what the user to select one of the contacts for which they have limited your app's access then you will need show your own ui using these contacts.

Remember that you do not need contact access permission to show CNContactPickerViewController because no long term access to contacts is being provided.

CNContactPickerViewController and limited contact access are two related, but independent ways of allowing the user to limit an app's access to their contacts.
CNContactPickerViewController allows the app to provide one-time access to a selected contact.  Your app doesn't need to request contact access permissions to use it.
Limited contact access provides your app with ongoing access to a selected set of contacts.  This provides the user with more control than the "full contact access" permission which grants an app ongoing access to all current and future contacts; A much broader permission than the user may desire.
If you do need ongoing access to a set of contacts and want the user to select one of those contacts then you will need to build your own selection screen.

Does Apple provide any controller like CNContactPickerViewController for select Limited Contact?

No. If you want the user to select one of the limited set of contacts that they have provided ongoing access to then you need to build that yourself. What is your use case?

If the user selects limited contact then I need to show only the selected contact same as 'CNContactPickerViewController' else display 'CNContactPickerViewController'.

That's not really what I meant. What is your use case for using limited contact access in the first place? What is your use case for the user then selecting one of those contacts?  Would it not be sufficient to allow the user to just use CNContactPickerViewController when required?  Why do you need ongoing access to a set of contacts?

Currently, I request contact permission and then open CNContactPickerViewController to let users select a contact to add to my app. However, with iOS 18, Apple introduced Limited Contact Access. Now, if the user grants limited access and selects five contacts, I’d like to display only those five contacts when they click 'Add Contact.' If full access is granted, I'll proceed with opening CNContactPickerViewController as usual. Could you advise on the best approach to implement this flow?

If you use CNContactPickerViewController then you don't need to request contact permission; that is the point of that picker. If you are requesting access to the users contacts (whether full or limited) then you would create your own picker that shows the contacts that are visible to your app.
